# Amazon Review Scraping using R

Tags: html, r, machine-learning, web-scraping, nlp

I'm trying to scrap Amazon review titles from the following link

https://www.amazon.in/Moto-Plus-Lunar-Grey-64GB/product-reviews/B071HWTHPH/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_show_all_top?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews&sortBy=recent&pageNumber=

Below is the code I'm using

```
moto_rating <- NULL
N_pages_rating <- 1
for (j in 1: N_pages_rating){
  t_rating <- read_html(paste0(url, j)) 
  s_rating <- cbind(t_rating %>% html_nodes(".review-rating") %>%  html_text())
  moto_rating <- rbind(s_rating,moto_rating)
```

The problem is I also get the Review Title of the "Top Positive Review" and "Top Critical Review" and it is getting extracted repeatedly since this appears in all the pages of review. I have highlighted it in the below link.

[image: Please click link]

I dont want the review titles of both "Top Positive Review" and "Top Critical Review" (as circled in red in the image above) to be extracted. But im not sure how should exclude it while extracting. Pls help

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about what you are trying to do but you should use the XPath to select a specific object from a webpage.

```
library(rvest)

url <- "https://www.amazon.in/Moto-Plus-Lunar-Grey-64GB/product-reviews/B071HWTHPH/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_show_all_top?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews&sortBy=recent&pageNumber="
moto_rating <- NULL
N_pages_rating <- 1
for (j in 1: N_pages_rating){
  t_rating <- read_html(paste0(url, j)) 
  s_rating <- cbind(t_rating %>% html_nodes(xpath = '/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[4]/i/span') %>%  html_text())
  moto_rating <- rbind(s_rating,moto_rating)
  }
```

You can see on this picture how to get the right XPath :

[image: Xpath]

I hope it will help.